# Matplotlib axis limits and text positions independent of dataset units

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make plots that are formatted the same way despite coming from different datasets and I'm running into issues with getting consistent text positions and appropriate axis limits because the datasets are not scaled exactly the same. For example - say I generate the following elevation profile:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Distance=np.array([1000,3000,7000,15000,20000])
Elevation=np.array([100,200,350,800,400])

def MyPlot(X,Y):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
    ax.plot(X,Y)
    fig.set_size_inches(fig.get_size_inches()*2)
    ax.set_ylim(min(Y)-50, max(Y)+500)
    ax.set_xlim(min(X)-50, max(X)+50)

    MaxPoint=X[np.argmax(Y)], max(Y)
    ax.scatter(MaxPoint[0], MaxPoint[1], s=10)
    ax.text(MaxPoint[0], MaxPoint[1]+100, s='Maximum = '+str(MaxPoint[1]), fontsize=8)

MyPlot(Distance,Elevation)
```

[image]

And then I have another dataset that's scaled differently:

```
Distance2=Distance*4
Elevation2=Elevation*5
MyPlot(Distance2,Elevation2)][2]][2]
```

[image]

Because of the fact that a unit change is relatively much larger in the first dataset than the second dataset, the text and axis labels do not get formatted as I'd like in the 2nd plot. Is there a way to adjust text position and axis limits that adjusts to the relative scale of the dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, for placing text with an offset such as this, you almost never want to use `text`.  Instead, use `annotate`.  The advantage is that you can give an offset of the text in *points* instead of data units.

Next, to reduce the density of tick locations, use `ax.locator_params` and change the `nbins` parameter.  `nbins` controls the tick density. Tick locations will still be automatically chosen, but reducing `nbins` will reduce the maximum number of tick locations.  If you do lower `nbins`, you may want to also change the numbers that matplotlib considers "even" when picking tick intervals.  That way, you have more options to get the expected number of ticks.

Finally, to avoid manually setting limits with a set padding, consider using `margins(some_percentage)` to pad the extents by a percentage of the current limits.

To show a complete example of all:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

distance=np.array([1000,3000,7000,15000,20000])
elevation=np.array([100,200,350,800,400])

def plot(x, y):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 2))

    # Plot your data and place a marker at the peak location
    maxpoint=x[np.argmax(y)], max(y)
    ax.scatter(maxpoint[0], maxpoint[1], s=10)
    ax.plot(x, y)

    # Reduce the maximum number of ticks and give matplotlib more flexibility
    # in the tick intervals it can choose.
    # Essentially, this will more or less always have two ticks on the y-axis
    # and 4 on the x-axis
    ax.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=3, steps=range(1, 11))
    ax.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=5, steps=range(1, 11))

    # Annotate the peak location. The text will always be 5 points from the
    # data location.
    ax.annotate('Maximum = {:0.0f}'.format(maxpoint[1]), size=8,
                xy=maxpoint, xytext=(5, 5), textcoords='offset points')

    # Give ourselves lots of padding on the y-axis, less on the x
    ax.margins(x=0.01, y=0.3)
    ax.set_ylim(bottom=y.min())

    # Set the aspect of the plot to be equal and add some x/y labels
    ax.set(xlabel='Distance', ylabel='Elevation', aspect=1)
    plt.show()

plot(distance,elevation)
```

[image]

And if we change the data:

```
plot(distance * 4, elevation * 5)
```

[image]

Finally, you might consider placing the annotation just above the top of the axis, instead of offset from the point:

```
ax.annotate('Maximum = {:0.0f}'.format(maxpoint[1]), ha='center',
            size=8, xy=(maxpoint[0], 1), xytext=(0, 5),
            textcoords='offset points',
            xycoords=('data', 'axes fraction'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.

Comment: FYI https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/5588 this was just merged to master which _should_ help with the tick density issue (and will be in 2.0)

Answer (score -3):

May be you should use `seaborn` where no any borders. I think it's very good way. 
It will be look like this:
[image: ok]

you should write string `import seaborn` at the beginning of the script.